# Where are the questions that I asked before on meta?

Tags: support, mso-mse-split

I was surprised about newly established **Meta Stack Overflow** has no reputation display but it's only displaying the Stack Overflow's reputation.

[I read that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250106/where-is-the-reputation-tab-on-mso) Meta is now really a real Stack Overflow Meta.

Anyway, I've no problem with the reputations changes. But where are my questions that I asked before?

I'm not seeing any questions that I asked before the Meta Stack Overflow website change.

Comment: Did you read the blog post about the migration?

Comment: sorry, no,, where's that?? please send me a link

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/; linked from the Community Bulletin on the right, and in the system message banner along the top.

Comment: oh! that's but where's my questions...

Comment: The *old* Meta Stack Overflow has been renamed to [metase], all your posts are still there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The old Meta Stack Overflow site has been renamed to **[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/)** and your [profile is still there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215599/c-link), questions and all.

The site was renamed to make space for a *real* per-site Meta for Stack Overflow, which you are looking at now. In the next few days *some* Stack Overflow-specific posts may be migrated here.

See the [blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/), which is linked from the system banner at the top and from the community bulletin box in the sidebar.

Because this is a proper per-site Meta, your reputation here is taken from Stack Overflow itself (synchronized once per hour). You can still earn badges, but up and downvotes on your questions and answers do not affect your reputation here or on Stack Overflow itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can see them on your [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215599/c-link) on [Meta StackExchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).