# Do not remove votes for non-fraud (puppet) user removal

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, upvotes, deleted-users

I just came across several user deletions the last couple of days in my history.

I am not much concerned about the reputation, but for sure, score is a type of measure on Stack Overflow how good a post is.

The help center says:

> This message means that a user who voted for one of your posts had their account deleted (either by request or due to violating the network's terms of service). As a result, all of their votes were removed, and the reputation you gained or lost from them was undone. The resultant reputation change could be any amount; it could even be a reputation gain if enough of the removed votes were downvotes.

I agree about the reputation removal if it is a fake account in question. However, if it is not, I am proposing not to remove the scores. Since scores are a valuable measure of the posts, I am personally inclined to think that these ought to remain around for user removal.

The rationale is that the post has been found useful or incorrect in the past which fact will most likely not change by the user removal itself. Therefore, some useful contribution to the site is removed. This can be even more appearing in less frequently visited tags where there are not so many votes happening.

Just to make it clear: I am referring both to upvotes and downvotes.

After all, edits and useful answers are not removed for user deletion, either.

Here is a bit of history for those who wish to read upon the topic, albeit none of those is a concrete and recent feature request for Stack Overflow:

[-10 For User was Removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252138/10-for-user-was-removed)

[Don't throw away all votes when a user is deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted)

Comment: If it's a puppet account, there's no reason to suspect any of the votes are legitimate. Get rid of them all. At the end, there should be no votes, no score, no rep.

Comment: Users are removed only in exceptional circumstances, overwhelmingly vote fraud. So naturally the votes are invalidated. They were never legitimate to start with.

Comment: @CodyGray: that is not true. I have seen offensive, but not fraud accounts removed, as well as users that are asking for deletion without any fraud vote.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: The proposal is about _non_-puppet or otherwise fraud account.

Comment: Then I misread it. But quite frankly, I'm against keeping *any* rep if  a user or content is removed. I don't care how old it is. If the content is gone (*especially* if it's my own choice to remove it), if the user is gone, my rep should be gone.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I am afraid the post is still not clear for you. As per the post, there is no content gone, just score. To be fair, the proposal does not even mention rep, just votes. You are focusing on the wrong thing imho. You are trying to approach it from reputation point of view, instead of the useful contribution, votes. Moreover, you first mention puppets, and now any accounts. I am somewhat lost now.

Comment: I don't see "offensive" accounts removed very often. Moderators will just suspend them. And high-reputation users that ask for account deletion, though still quite rare, go through a separate process, as [Jarrod describes here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/156520/153008). My point is that the user accounts that are deleted outright are *primarily* illegitimate accounts; the other cases are rare exceptions that are hardly worth optimizing for.

Comment: @CodyGray: no, repetitively offensive accounts are removed, which I have seen happening. You will not go and get suspended all the time. Rightfully, the Xth such issue will cause deletion. More importantly, I have seen several not high-rep users removing their account. In fact, it is quite rare that high-rep users remove their account in comparison with low-rep users. Low-rep users come and go, whereas high-rep users only go in exceptional cases.

Comment: I'm equating content *and* votes *and* users. If the user is gone, the votes should be gone, therefore my score should be gone along with my reputation. I extended it further with content. If that's gone, same thing. Most of my content is entirely useless as it is, so it's no real loss if being honest. I don't deserve 95% of the reputation I have.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: sorry, I am lost what content you are talking about. I am also lost whether you talk about puppets or any account. I am also lost why you keep repeating "if a user is gone, everything must be gone" without reasoning why so.

Comment: I could put forth the argument for transparency. All score, all reputation, all *trust* should be directly tied to both users and content that are visible to everybody. But in reality, my world view is that most votes and such are quite meaningless and no real effort should be made to hold on to it. Expending developer effort on it seems quite absurd to me. But again, that's my world view, yours may differ.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: well, yes, it differs. I share the community's view about votes: they are useful contribution to the site, and hence hearing that they are not, is absurd to me, when they are the primary measure for post quality on this site.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Also, you keep mentioning reputation loss, whereas the proposal is about upvotes **and** downvotes, i.e. score focused rather than reputation. That means if a deleted account is removed, you gain reputation if the account was downvoting you. Reputation is just a side-effect; I was going to discuss the real contribution value here, not reputation gain and loss.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, but I totally disagree with you. The impact on any one person should be minimal if the activity was legitimate.

It's important to have a consistent approach to account deletion - exclusions mean loopholes which become hard to police (and fraudulent voters will try and exploit them). Exclusions also mean more edge cases, which incurs more work and potentially more mistakes.

The real question is: how do you *prove* that the deleted account was "real" and not used in whole or part for fraudulent activity? Sure, you can argue that some accounts (belonging to well known identities) have a certain level of integrity, but those people seldom delete their accounts. How do you prove it for all the other accounts which belong to regular users?

Comment: I do not understand this post. There are two different cases, already. That would not change with the proposal either. Moreover, you are claiming you cannot prove if it is a fraud or not fraud account (whereas accounts are frequently deleted being puppets), but you want to assume bad faith that it is always fraud, even if someone decides to leave SO on his/her own. That is not good, I am afraid. So, even if it was all true, which I do not think it is personally, you would need to improve the system to catch them, rather than letting the issue introduce more issues.

Comment: `how do you prove that the deleted account was "real"` Super mod powers? What do you think we have mods for?

Comment: @bjb568 I am a mod on a different site. The SE developers can forensically examine an account, moderators cannot. Proving that an account is a sock that has been fraudulently used is normally pretty easy (most people who try to game the system are not too sophisticated), proving the converse is quite difficult. In any case, what's the loss of a few votes upon someone deleting their account? If it's more than a few then maybe there was serial voting going on, just at a low level?

Comment: @FinalContest I don't understand your comment. You have misinterpreted what I said. Mods do not *assume* bad faith or fraudulent account at all. Please go back and read paragraph 2 of my answer.

Comment: If everybody who ever experienced a "your rep changed by -10 due to a deleted user" event and who did not commit a fraud to get those +10 rep shouted "here" now, we would be deaf, I guess.  It has happened to everyone being active on SO for a year or so.  That fact shows pretty clearly that removing the votes of deleted users *quite often* removes non-fraudulent votes.  So this motion is valid in my eyes.

Comment: @Alfe Users are deleted for all sorts of reasons. It would incur too much resource for the staff or moderators to analyze each one and determine which votes should be kept, simply so that someone doesn't lose 10 or 20 imaginary points. Unfortunately it's a fact of life, as you say we've all lost rep that way. Just suck it up and go earn some more.