# Where did my rep go?

Tags: support, reputation, meta

About 20 minutes ago I had 10100 rep, and now I see it is missing some ~36 or so rep (I just got an upvote so less now) -- but I don't see anything in my rep history to support the change.

However my meta account still shows the 10100 (now 10110) rep correctly. What happened to my main site rep?

Here is a screenshot of my main account:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and here is my meta account to show the discrepancy.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So what happened to the rep? and why can't I see the changes in my rep history?

Note: This isn't about [*"User was Removed."*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252138/10-for-user-was-removed) The  bug is that my main site rep history isn't reflecting the changes like it should.

Comment: Not only reputation, missing golden badges too -_-

Comment: I think badges don't carry over for meta. rep however does.

Comment: Meta rep isn't updated in real time.  It syncs every few hours.

Comment: @Servy few hours :O, time for new servers xD

Comment: Do you have show removed posts checked?  A post of yours was likely deleted.

Comment: @Servy still doesn't answer the question of why I can't see where this rep went. those screen shots were take just now, and by your logic the SO screen shot should show the rep change, but it doesn't.

Comment: @CustomizedName That assumes it's actually important to have it update in real time.  Clearly SE disagrees with that prioritization.

Comment: @Servy how do I toggle said option?

Comment: @rlemon You click the check box.

Comment: @Servy, let me rephrase, I see no checkbox on my rep tab or preferences tab. I should also mention /reputation also omits the change.

Comment: I imagine something wonky happened with that user removal. The history event that would correspond to that removal says "old rep = 10110, new rep = 10064". Yet in the reputation history it says you gained 4.

Comment: @animuson yes that is also very confusing for me. yet my meta profile shows my rep and I was having a discussion just yesterday in the chats about how I needed *one more rep* for a nice number.

Comment: @rlemon http://i.stack.imgur.com/mUZ3O.png

Comment: @Servy thanks, and no that wasn't the case. I don't see any of my posts deleted recently. as a side note: silly place for the checkbox.

Comment: just a thought: if a user was removed and they had downvoted me for a total of -4, but upvoted me for a total of +36, would the system maybe only show me the -4 reversal?

Comment: @rlemon No, it would show you the net change that occurred from all the votes being reversed. Or at least, it's *supposed* to do that.

Comment: then this is strange indeed.

Comment: @Ben also just a side thought about the sync. the upvote that just landed on my account reflected on meta instantly. just makes this even more confusing :P

Comment: @rlemon Your reputation was already 10,110 before this happened (as of that upvote from 10 hours ago), and that's what Meta is reflecting. The removal dropped you down to 10,064 and then the recent upvote is what bumped you to 10,074. Meta profiles are updated from the main site once an hour, there are no exceptions and there's no manual process (even for moderators) of avoiding that caching restriction.

Comment: @animuson ahh, makes sense. okay, but that still doesn't explain why I see +4 but lost rep :P

Comment: To the close voter -- this is still an issue, my rep change is not being reflected in my rep history.

Comment: @rlemon It takes some time until rep is synchronized on meta, and there's certainly a dupe for this question (seen it just a few days before).

Comment: @pi I am told it takes an hour, which is fine. that isn't the question. The two profiles now do a nice job of outlining that within the last day I had that rep and now it is gone with no record of it on my reputation history

Comment: To the close voter; even if this was a misunderstanding about the site it would still be on-topic as MSO is the support site...

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: @rlemon **I'm not _@pi_!** Refer to user addresses correctly please (_@πάντα ῥεῖ_). Yes, I was that close voter, could you elaborate please, how my comment doesn't solve your question?

Comment: @ShadowWizard see Anna's answer, the issue isn't about why the rep is gone, the issue (now) is that it isn't being displayed properly.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ sorry, but if I'm on mobile I am not going through the hassle of typing your insane unicode username. also see my comment above and Anna's answer below.

Comment: @rlemon _"... of typing your insane unicode ..."_ That's quite not _insane_ at all (like Sheldon, I've been tested about this already, and proved to be _"normal"_ ;) ), but very conscious (check my profile statement about this please)!

Comment: still a copy and paste only name for me, and on mobile that is still a PITA. so yes, for me it is an insane username because it is hard for me to interact with you. take it or leave it. but this digresses from the issue.

Comment: @rlemon _"... it is hard for me to interact with you"_ That's intentional, all my point is about this! _"but this digresses from the issue."_ Surely!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Oh boy, this is thorny.

The gist of what happened was that multiple users were deleted and your reputation was recalculated as a result and you dropped 46 rep (from 10110 to 10064).

Why this shows up as +4 on your reputation tab is a good question. The exact sequence of events is painful to reconstruct because the recalc already happened and that effectively normalizes all rep events that remain. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thankyou, I think most of my confusion here was that I was seeing the +4 as well as the rep drop and trying to guess what happened. All the while dealing with the deleted users spamming the chats again :/ it's been a fun afternoon :)

Comment: @rlemon To be honest, I doubt that there's an actual bug here beyond display confusion as a result of rewriting history. I'll dig more tomorrow, but it might have to wait to be fully investigated till Nick Craver's around/available.

Comment: [according to animuson it should reflect the net change](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270670/where-did-my-rep-go/270673?noredirect=1#comment90227_270670), which makes complete sense. not being able to see this in my rep history (I would argue) is a bug.

Comment: Well, here's sort of the thing... What we're showing on your profile doesn't seem to match what I'm seeing as a net change with the dev tools. But, I'm not sure if this is an issue of logging, timing, or something else. I suspect daily rep limits are somehow involved, but that's pure speculation at this point.

Comment: I was once in a project that had to monitor amount of gas of each user (a company) in a gas storage system. It involved similar operations to reputation here: basically you can gain or loose some amount of gas due to some events that happen in the system. There was really no way to see what had happened for any averagely complicated scenario in production, until we had complete logging (in the sense of domain objects, not log files) of every possible event that could influence the records (recalculation with its reasons explained being one of them). Before that - I can feel your pain ;)

Comment: As a complete outsider, is it possible that some of the loss is being accounted by removing elements from the history (which would only be noticed on the profile if you went back through the rep pages and knew exactly when you got which upvote to compare) and the +4 is just from downvotes being recovered?