# Why are my reputation points reduced every Sunday on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

It's nearly six week. Every Sunday night my reputation points are reduced by some points without any reason. The "Recent Achievement" option does not show any deduction, but the reputation points are reduced. No downvotes, not anything, but the reputation points are gone. I lost 11 points this Sunday. Why is this happening to me? Can anyone explain it?

Comment: If you've gained reputation from now-deleted posts that could be part of it. This might be helpful: [How do I audit my reputation?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43004/how-do-i-audit-my-reputation)

Comment: [Check your reputation history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6128495/gaurav-mahindra?tab=reputation&sort=time)

Comment: OMG, eleven points?? This is an outrage! No actually its not.  That's just barely more than one upvote.  Don't worry about points so much, they really are not that important.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You [don't have a consistent loss of points every Sunday night](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6128495/gaurav-mahindra?tab=reputation&sort=time), though you are having a fairly consistent loss of rep points weekly.

You've had some downvotes, a [user was removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252138/10-for-user-was-removed) and an answer was unaccepted.

[image]

Looks like a coincidence, but if you notice that the breakdown is consistent downvoting then flag one of your posts for mod attention if you suspect [serial downvoting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes).

Comment: Thanks for your precious time and help. I got it.

Comment: @GauravMahindra you're welcome and thank you for being so nice :)