# What happened to my meta activity?

Tags: bug, questions, meta, mso-mse-split

I just asked a question on stackoverflow meta.  It said it was the first question I've asked.  I've been using the site for a bunch of years and it's definitely not the first question I've asked on meta.  What happened?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/156736/smartcaveman

Comment: @HansPassant - oh. thanks

Comment: Notsosmartcaveman

Comment: @Will lol funny guy

Answer (score 9):

Seems you slept through the [mso-mse-split](/questions/tagged/mso-mse-split):

[Operation 'Split, All The Metas!' Shall Commence On April 16, 2014](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/228888)
[100 days later, was the split a good idea?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266742)
[Where are the questions that I asked before on meta?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/250892)